# r extract subset of a data set with field name

Tags: r, function, tidyverse

I am using R tidyverse package to extract several subsets of a large data set each matching a specific field name. However since the number of subsets to be extracted is large, and extracting one by one with a specific expression is time consuming and wonder if there is a faster way to do this.

Here is a minimal example: 
The data frame looks like this and is called "dummy":

```
A <- c(605, 605, 608, 608)
B <- c(5, 6, 3, 4)
C <- c(500, 600, 300, 400)
dummy <-as.data.frame(A, B, C)
```

AT present what I do is:

```
subject1 <- filter(dummy, A == "605")
subject2 <- filter(dummy, A == "608")
```

Since there are 100 subjects in my original data set, this process is time consuming and wonder if there is a faster method to do this.
 I note that the numbers are in the column A are in order but not consecutive, as shown in the example.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a loop. However, as @akrun had mentioned, you could end up with a lot of objects in the global environment. For example if you had 200 subjects, then you'll have 200 objects (very messy), perhaps you could consider what your next steps will be and see if you can achieve what you're trying to do without creating a lot of objects

```
subjects <- c(605, 608) 

for (i in 1:length(subjects)) {

  object_name <- paste0("subject", i)
  assign(object_name, filter(dummy, A == subjects[i]))

}
```

Comment: Great tips. It is true that lots of objects are created in the global environment. This is the process of cleaning data. I intend to use each subject data within another R file using a temporary environment.

Answer (score 1):

We can do a `split` (should be faster compared to `==`) into a `list` of `data.frame`s

```
lst1 <- split(dummy, dummy$A)
```

NOTE: Creating multiple objects in the global environment is not recommended

Once we have a `list`, it is easier to process/apply functions in each `list` element with `lapply/sapply` etc.

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) colMeans(x[-1]))
```

NOTE:  If it is a group by operation, we don't need to `split` it

```
aggregate(.~ A, dummy, FUN = mean)
```

#### data

```
dummy <- data.frame(A, B, C)
```

Comment: Even the great @akrun forgets `by` (which can replace `split` + `lapply`)!

Comment: @Parfait  I know you like `by` very much.  For me (I don't consider myself great or anything), the `by` returns with some new format output (which can be changed though).  Also, for some strange reason, I don't remember `by` when I try to solve a question